# R: replace underscore repeated non-consecutively more than twice

Tags: r, regex

I received a dataset with phrases connected by underscores like so:

```
text <- "hi, how_are_you? that's_great. yes_i'm_als0_@k"
```

As in this example, the data contain numbers, symbols, punctuation, and spaces. I want to replace underscores when they appear 3 or more times (like in `yes_i'm_als0_@k`) with single spaces. The desired output is:

```
"hi, how_are_you? that's_great. yes i'm als0 @k"
```

Another way to put it, I received a dataset with hard-coded ngrams and I want to keep unigrams, bigrams and trigrams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gsubfn` is like `gsub` but instead of the replacing occurrences of the regular expression specified in the first argument with a fixed string it passes the matches to the function specified in the second argument replacing the input with the output of the function.  The function can be specified in formula notation where the body of the function is on the right hand side and the argument, here just `s`, is determined by finding the free variables in the right hand side.

```
library(gsubfn)

gsubfn("\\S+", 
  ~ if (length(unlist(gregexpr("_", s))) >= 3) gsub("_", " ", s) else s, 
  text)
```

giving:

```
[1] "hi, how_are_you? that's_great. yes i'm als0 @k"
```